# fsck: error 2 (no such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/nvme01p2

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem, initramfs, nvme

Using Ubuntu 20.04 on a brand-new Lenovo T490.

It came with Windows 10 but I installed Ubuntu 20.04 over it. At first, I started noticing random freezes, so I had to do hard resets every time. After a while the computer didn't boot more. It got stuck in the Lenovo screen at startup.

I changed the laptop for a brand-new one at work and after installing Ubuntu, I started to have the same freeze issues again. Managed to reset it by ALT + Imp Pt + REISUB a couple of times, but then that didn't work anymore, and I was back at holding the power button.

This until today when I started to get filesystem errors. It requested a manual `fsck` on the 'root filesystem' and I tried that but I got a fsck error 2. See the picture:

[image]

UPDATE: I managed to run fsck sucessfully, I don't remember how. Noticed the computer tried downloading something wile connected trough cable.

The issue behind this seems to be with a linux-wide bug with certain SSDs, including my Kingston SA2000. The following is a guide to fix it:
https://tekbyte.net/2020/fixing-nvme-ssd-problems-on-linux/

Comment: Many Lenovo's need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. Make sure those are most current versions first. Power button shutdown often causes file corruption. REISUB only safe way to shutdown. Also with NVMe you have to have drive/partition correct for fsck. /dev/nvme0n1p1, not nvme01p1.

Comment: can't find any nvme on /dev

Comment: That is why you have to update UEFI &  NVMe firmware.

Comment: What can I do now????

Comment: Did you run a correct fsck command? Did you check lenovo site to see if you have most current UEFI?